# Searching for a certain string name in Windows registry with a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I wonder if it's possible to find and delete certain given registry values by the user in the Windows registry with a bat file.

For example, I want to delete all the entries which contains the word `oracle`, so the bat file must delete all the entries like for example:

`c:\users\user\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_101\`
`Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle`
`c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin\OraOLEDB11.DLL`

As you can see, the 3 entries have the word `oracle` in it. Is this possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: May be this useful: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html

Comment: It is unclear, what you are trying to match precisely (Anywhere? Whole words only? If so, what are the delimiters?). It also appears, that you aren't looking for values to match, but rather the data they store. Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 commands that will fit your requirements: [`reg query`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc742028(v=ws.10).aspx) and [`reg delete`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc742145(v=ws.10).aspx).

With `req query` you can search for keys and/or values in the registry.

> ```
> reg query <KeyName> [{/v <ValueName> | /ve}] [/s] [/se <Separator>] [/f <Data>] [{/k | /d}] [/c] [/e] [/t <Type>] [/z]
> ```

The following example searching recursive (`/s`) in `HKCU`:

```
reg query HKCU /s /f Oracle
```

To delete a registry key or value use `reg delete`:

> ```
> Reg delete <KeyName> [{/v ValueName | /ve | /va}] [/f]
> ```

To write it in a batch you have to filter the output of `reg query` a bit and parse it line by line with a `for /F` loop. If you have trouble with that show your efforts and ask about specific problems (edit your question).

Also consider of making a backup with [`reg export`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc742017(v=ws.10).aspx) of selected keys before you delete them.

> ```
> Reg export KeyName FileName [/y]
> ```

---

Another great tool for such things is the [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell).

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, I'll try it that way.